# Create Tab Separated File with Iterative Values Python

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I want to create a tab separated file that contains this format:

```
chr3R    4000000    4005000
chr3R    4005000    4010000
chr3R    4010000    4015000
chr3R    4015000    4020000
...
chr3R   32070000   32075000
chr3R   32075000   32080000
```

Each line the value of the second and third column has a difference of 5,000.

What is the best way to do this? Pandas or to create a text file?

Thank you.

Rodrigo

Comment: You're newish here, but not completely new.   I suggest you review [help] to see what questions are appropriate, and maybe fix this question up to be appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just write a quick script using the `range` built-in:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python                                                           

for i in range(4000, 32080, 5):
    print "chr3R\t%d\t%d" % (i * 1000, (i + 5) * 1000)
```

Then pipe to a file like this:

```
python [script name] > [outfile]
```

Comment: Hi Ann, I tab between the first and second columns, but a space between the second and third columns. I tried using the Unix Unexpand program to replace the space between the second and third column but got two tabs by this method. How can I modify your script to create the tab between second and third column. Thanks.

Comment: The tab character is `\t` so you can put that where ever you need, or replace it with a space `' '`.